# r map2 yields mapply issue

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to build an updated copy of mlbgameday, and am running into a weird error. I'm also not well practiced at asking questions, so fee free to nudge me on how to do this right.

Here is the code:

```
library(mlbgday)
library(dplyr)
library(doSNOW)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cores=4)
library(Rmpi)
library(doMPI)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(utils)
library(foreach)
library(stats)
library(DBI)
library(magrittr)
library(xml2)

games<-get_payload(start = "2021-04-01", end = "2021-11-02")
```

'''

The error I get is this: Error in mapply(.f, .x, .y, MoreArgs = list(...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

I don't have mapply() in any of my code and the traceback yields:

```
traceback()
11: mapply(.f, .x, .y, MoreArgs = list(...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
10: map2(data, directions, function(column, direction) {
        proxy <- vec_proxy_order(column)
        desc <- identical(direction, "desc")
        if (is.data.frame(proxy)) {
            proxy <- order(vec_order(proxy, direction = direction, 
                na_value = if (desc) 
                    "smallest"
                else "largest"))
        }
        else if (desc) {
            proxy <- desc(proxy)
        }
        proxy
    })
9: arrange_rows(.data, dots)
8: arrange.data.frame(., tfs_zulu)
7: dplyr::arrange(., tfs_zulu)
6: dplyr::mutate(., num = as.numeric(num))
5: tidyr::fill(., num, .direction = "up")
4: na.omit(.)
3: dplyr::bind_rows(acts, bats) %>% dplyr::arrange(tfs_zulu) %>% 
       dplyr::mutate(num = as.numeric(num)) %>% tidyr::fill(num, 
       .direction = "up") %>% na.omit() at payload_methods.R#229
2: payload.gd_inning_all(urlz) at get_payload.R#127
1: get_payload(start = "2021-04-01", end = "2021-11-02")
```

This tells me that it's a dplyr() issue?

If you've run into this, please let send suggestions. Also, I'm working on a package so I'm not sure how to attach it for your review.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide working examples of `data` and `directions` provided as the output of `dput()`.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I don't have any data to provide -- mlbgameday gets the data. I've added the entire code above.